# onPress of back button from settings it returns to home screen not the current activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

### What is happening:

- I am in my app screen, it is a fragment residing in a activity
- I receive the message, i open the message by going to inbox
- now i press back, now it takes me to my home screen

***note:*** I can see the app running in the background

### What i am trying to do:

I  want to go to by fragment on press of back from settings screen

***Code i use to start the current fragment was:***

```
ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    FrgOtp fragment2 = FrgOtp.newInstance(phoneNumber);  
                    ft.hide(FrgLogin.this);
                    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment2, FrgOtp.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(FrgOtp.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
```

**manifest**

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.windhyaworks.activities.ActLogin"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ft.addtobackstack()?